# Detect a factory default NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc

How to detect a factory default NFC tag on android?

```
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_TAG);

    NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag); // should be not null when factory default
    Ndef tagNdef = Ndef.get(tag); // should be null when factory default
```

I couldn't use this criteria, because sometimes a non empty NDEF tag is considered NdefFormatable (I think that is an incomplete reading).

Comment: Wouldn't a tag that has an NDEF message still be considered NdefFormatable?

Comment: In few cases, i got a NDEF tag NdefFormatable. I think that my device couldn't read correctly (scan interrupt, or another situation).